# Locate the largest gap in a sequence of numerical values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

We have a large table with a field `MEMBERNO`. The values are roughly sequential with a few gaps due to rows being deleted (the next number logic is a simple

```
MAX(MEMBERNO) + 1
```

In T-SQL, can I locate the largest gap between 2 values? I know that I coudl do it with a cursor but am interested to see if it can be done in T-SQL.

So if the sequence is `1,2,4,6,8,12,13,14,15,18` I would like to return `12` as it is the number after the largest gap

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175780(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: @Mihai - thanks so much. Could you put it as an answer please so that I can mark it as the correct one?

Comment: an answer is more than a link,wait for somebody to put in the effort,I`m too lazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use LAG to get the previous memberno and calculate the gap:

```
select top(1) memberno, memberno - lag(memberno) over (order by memberno) as gap
from members
order by gap desc;
```

Here is the SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/79bc7/6.

Here is the same with a sub query instead of LAG:

```
select top(1) memberno, memberno - 
  (select max(memberno) from members x where x.memberno < members.memberno) as gap
from members
order by gap desc;
```

The SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79bc7/2.

Comment: Thorsten - many thanks. Unfortunately LAG is not an available function in SQL Server 2008

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't know that. LAG is of course the first thing to come to mind. So straight-forward. In simple selects like this you can easily replace it with a sub query, however. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Change it to sql server 2008 so there woudnt be any doubt.

Comment: Thanks anyway Thorsten. We are upgrading soon to 2012 and that will stick in my mind as a possible solution

Comment: Yes, Mihai, you are right, I've changed the fiddle accordingly.

Comment: Thanks both - that second non LAG query works an absolute treat!